# How to remove an auto-generated extra column from sdk:DataGrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-toolkit

I have a datagrid in Silverlight whose ItemsSource is set to an ObservableCollection. The default generation of columns is also set to true, so I don't define columns manually. Is there a way to remove a column from the data grid after its ItemsSource is set? Currently I'm getting an extra column that I do not need.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of, no, hide yes.

In the grids AutoGeneratingColumn function, you can do

```
if (e.PropertyName == "unwanted_one")
  e.Column.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: You can get rid of the column altogether by preventing it being added to the columns via the `Cancel` property on the eventargs

Comment: Fair enough. I hadnt thought of that. Hiding it is almost as good. :) as at least it doesnt bother you

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid` as a `AutoGeneratingColumn` event which fires for each column that is being generated.

This event gives you considerable flexibility in modifying the actual column created. It also has a `Cancel` property on its event args to cancel the creation of specific column.

```
e.Cancel = e.PropertyName == "NotRequiredProperty";
```